Magento 2 : Saved data not in DB after throw new LocalizedException
save some records to DB and after throw LocalizedException, the saved data does not show in the table. auto increment ID is assigned
$data = [
            'sku' => $f_sku,
            'user' => $adminUsername, // Assuming admin is saving the product
            'product_status' => $f_product_status, // Product status from submission
            'log' => $product_type ."\n" .str_replace( "<br>", "\n" , $comment),
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'status' => $save_status, // Validation status
        ];
    /** @var \Ef\Bundle\Model\BundleLog $bundleLog */
    $bundleLog = $this->bundleLogFactory->create();
    $bundleLog->setData($data);
    try {

        $this->bundleLogRepository->save($bundleLog);
        $this->addLogs->add_error('event_before_save_products', $data, 'validate_products');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Error saving bundle log: %1', $e->getMessage()));
    }

    if($error  ) { // if having a error
        throw new LocalizedException(__($comment));
    }


Try code like this :
    try 
    {
         $data = [
            'sku' => $f_sku,
            'user' => $adminUsername, // Assuming admin is saving the product
            'product_status' => $f_product_status, // Product status from submission
            'log' => $product_type ."\n" .str_replace( "<br>", "\n" , $comment),
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'status' => $save_status, // Validation status
         ];
         /** @var \Ef\Bundle\Model\BundleLog $bundleLog */
         $bundleLog = $this->bundleLogFactory->create();
         $bundleLog->setData($data);
    
         $this->bundleLogResource->save($bundleLog);
         $this->addLogs->add_error('event_before_save_products', $data, 'validate_products');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Error saving bundle log: %1', $e->getMessage()));
    }

    if($error  ) { // if having a error
        throw new LocalizedException(__($comment));
    }

NOTE : On Above code bundleLogResource is the object of your resource model, it is like this \Ef\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleLog

Try this
Replace this line
$this->bundleLogRepository->save($bundleLog);

To this

$bundleLog->save();

